# Why is amplifying changing the envelope value of speech signal?

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition

I am working on speech signal with envelope extraction. I use the standard deviation (std) at each point of the envelope value.  However, the std value changes when I amplify the speech. What is the logic behind this? From my understanding, the more stable speech, the lower standard deviation, no matter how high the volume is. This is because the envelope will take the shape of the signal. I don't get it why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a signal x with samples x1,x2,x3... and want to compute the standard deviation you can use one of the formulas specified here: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/std.html.
If you try either out with, for example, a signal with 3 samples x1=1,x2=2,x3=3 and second signal which is an amplified version of the first (e.g., x1=2,x2=4,x3=6) you'll see that the amplification affects the std (by a factor 2 in this case). Try writing the formulas out and you can derive how amplification affect the std. Was that the question?

Comment: You amplify the speech, you amplify the envelope, you amplify the std (since `std(a*x)=a*std(x)`)

Comment: Exactly, regardless of the signal

Comment: Thanks schvaba986 and Itamar Katz. Now I get it. Really solve my question in my head. If you dont mind...can u suggest what is other mathematical way to observe data stability(in speech specifically). ? I am not good in math but have to do it.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by data stability. Are you interested in how stationary (so mean and variance do not change) your signal is? You can check out these threads, there are some examples: 
http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8436/are-there-any-measurements-or-test-for-whether-an-audio-signal-is-stationary

http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-to-check-if-a-timeseries-is-stationary

Comment: Hi Schvaba986., What I meant from the data stability is, the peak of the envelope. I already extracted the local maxima, now I want to measure it whether it is stable (imagine flat) or not (imagine not stable). However, my system should be able to deal with any volume of speech because it will only consider the shape of the envelope.I dont know what measurement should I use,Do u have any suggestion?I have went through the link that u provided but I need time to understand it. I believed this is really simple but don't know how..Thanks a lot